# BATCH : The terminator ' is missing in the string

Tags: command-line, powershell, cpu, batch

I'm currently developping a small batch script which is supposed to get my processor informations (and his current frequency) to print them in the standard output.

My problem : when I try to execute the commands in PowerShell or directly in the CMD everything is fine, but when I try to execute the batch file I have the error (my computer is in french):

```
Le terminateur ' est manquant dans la chaîne.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Which is something like this in english :

```
The terminator ' is missing in the string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I tried to run my code line by line and I found that the bug come from the line where I test if the computer is in english (because the counters have different names in french and in english).

I think the error is in this line (and more precisely the '%' because when I remove it everything works):
`$ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Performance' -ErrorAction:Ignore).CounterSamples.CookedValue;`

My code :

```
powershell -Command "$ISlistOfProcessors = (Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor | Select-Object @{n='ProcessorModel';e={$_.Name}},Caption,DeviceID,CurrentClockSpeed,MaxClockSpeed,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors); for($i=0; $i -lt $ISlistOfProcessors.Length+1; $i++){$ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Performance' -ErrorAction:Ignore).CounterSamples.CookedValue; if(!$ProcessorPerformance){$ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter '\Informations sur le processeur(_Total)\Pourcentage de performances du processeur').CounterSamples.CookedValue};$ISlistOfProcessors[$i].CurrentClockSpeed=[math]::Round($ISlistOfProcessors[$i].MaxClockSpeed*($ProcessorPerformance/100));} $ISlistOfProcessors"

pause
```

and in a format more readable (I just made some return to line, and I only execute the code above):

```
powershell -Command "
$ISlistOfProcessors = (Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor | Select-Object @{n='ProcessorModel';e={$_.Name}},Caption,DeviceID,CurrentClockSpeed,MaxClockSpeed,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors); 
for($i=0; $i -lt $ISlistOfProcessors.Length+1; $i++){
   $ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Performance' -ErrorAction:Ignore).CounterSamples.CookedValue; 
   if(!$ProcessorPerformance){
      $ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter '\Informations sur le processeur(_Total)\Pourcentage de performances du processeur').CounterSamples.CookedValue
   }
   $ISlistOfProcessors[$i].CurrentClockSpeed=[math]::Round($ISlistOfProcessors[$i].MaxClockSpeed*($ProcessorPerformance/100));
} 
$ISlistOfProcessors"

pause
```

Does anyone have any idea why I get this error only when I run the batch script?

Thx for the help and sorry for my bad english (I'm french).

Comment: You do not show a single line of batch in your question but you do in your answer.  Does this problem have ANYTHING to do with cmd.exe's batch?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas no, technically this is powershell, but driven from a batch script, which makes debugging very hard.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas the code I show in my first post is a batch script calling powershell to execute a command, and yes it's mostly powershell but the bug is from the batch

Comment: @LPChip when I posted that comment, he didn't have ***any*** of the batch stuff in his question but batch in the title and in the tags.  Yes, I too understand.  I have spent literally HOURS trying to escape some powershell commands to be run from batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution while trying to put the name of the counter in a variable.

My problem was the '%' in the my command because the batch file was certainly searching for a variable name. So I just made a variable with the name of the counter :

```
set counterName='\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Performance'

powershell -Command "$ISlistOfProcessors = (Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor | Select-Object @{n='ProcessorModel';e={$_.Name}},Caption,DeviceID,CurrentClockSpeed,MaxClockSpeed,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors); for($i=0; $i -lt $ISlistOfProcessors.Length+1; $i++){$ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter %counterName% -ErrorAction:Ignore).CounterSamples.CookedValue; if(!$ProcessorPerformance){$ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter '\Informations sur le processeur(_Total)\Pourcentage de performances du processeur').CounterSamples.CookedValue};$ISlistOfProcessors[$i].CurrentClockSpeed=[math]::Round($ISlistOfProcessors[$i].MaxClockSpeed*($ProcessorPerformance/100));}$ISlistOfProcessors"
```

In fact I just replaced this line :

```
$ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Performance' -ErrorAction:Ignore).CounterSamples.CookedValue;
```

By this line :

```
$ProcessorPerformance = (Get-Counter -Counter %counterName% -ErrorAction:Ignore).CounterSamples.CookedValue;
```